# Extract name of function and arguments in separate text

Tags: python, string

I am trying to extract words only from the body of the function. Below you can see my text.

```
# Example of estimation
## Example of estimation
### Example of estimation

"Some calculation"
""" Note : 
           The data here is artificial.
           Idea is to show how code will look like after estimation.
           More information www.google.com
"""

@iterate_jit(nopython=True)
def fun_min_ssc(min_wage, tax_rate,calc_min_profit):
     calc_min_profit= min_wage * tax_rate + min_wage - (min_wage*2)
     return calc_min_profit
```

Text that starting with : #,##,###,”,""", @ is not needed.

Now I want to extract only arguments from the body of the function such as :

- Name of the function: **fun_min_ssc** and
- Arguments of the function : **min_wage, tax_rate,calc_min_profit**

I tried to solve this problem with the function below :

```
f= open("text.txt","w+")
f.write('''# Example of estimation
## Example of estimation
### Example of estimation

"Some calculation"
""" Note : 
           The data here is artificial.
           Idea is to show how code will look like after estimation.
           More information www.google.com
"""

@iterate_jit(nopython=True)
def cal_min_ssc(min_wage, tax_rate,min_profit):
     min_profit = min_wage * tax_rate + min_wage - (min_wage*2)
     return min_profit
''')
for line in f.readlines():
    print(line, end='')
f.close()

os.getcwd()
 os.listdir()
os.chdir('C:/') <---Import your path

file_reader = open('C:/text.txt')   <----Import your path
os.getcwd()
# Open the file in read mode 
text = open("text.txt", "r") 



# Creating dictonary and count freqency
d = dict() 


# Loop through each line of the file 
for line in text: 
    # Remove the leading spaces and newline character 
    line = line.strip() 
  
    # Convert the characters in line to  
    # lowercase to avoid case mismatch 
    line = line.lower() 
  
    # Split the line into words 
    words = line.split(" ") 
    words = line.split(",") 
    words = line.split("*") 
  
    # Iterate over each word in line 
    for word in words: 
        # Check if the word is already in dictionary 
        if word in d: 
            # Increment count of word by 1 
            d[word] = d[word] + 1
        else: 
            # Add the word to dictionary with count 1 
            d[word] = 1

# Print the contents of dictionary 
for key in list(d.keys()): 
    print(key, ":", d[key])
```

So can anybody help me how to solve this problem or suggest some other approach that can solve this problem ?

Comment: You should look into the `ast` library, that is made for parsing python files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might get you on the right track. I have used a regex statement as a specific search criteria to find the lines that start with `def` and end with `:`.

```py
x = re.search(r"^def.*:$", line)
```

Once I have the line in question, I split the line using `def`  and the opening bracket of the function `(`. This allows me to easily grab the function name.

```py
values = x[0].split('def ')[1].split('(')
function_name = values[0]
```

I then have to grab the other section, but remove the last two characters ie.  `):`

```py
arguments = values[1][:-2].split(', ')
```

As the arguments are separated by a comma, I can then use that as a split separator. However, I must warn you, make sure they are consistently separated in the same way...i.e.  with or without a space after the comma.

I have printed the desired output, however, you can add these items to a list or whatever structure you desire:

Here is my example code (without all the file input stuff):

```py
import re


text = '''# Example of estimation
## Example of estimation
### Example of estimation

"Some calculation"
""" Note : 
           The data here is artificial.
           Idea is to show how code will look like after estimation.
           More information www.google.com
"""

@iterate_jit(nopython=True)
def cal_min_ssc(min_wage, tax_rate, min_profit):
     min_profit = min_wage * tax_rate + min_wage - (min_wage*2)
     return min_profit
'''

lines = text.split('\n')
for line in lines:
    x = re.search(r"^def.*:$", line)
    if x != None:
        values = x[0].split('def ')[1].split('(')
        function_name = values[0]
        arguments = values[1][:-2].split(', ')
        print(f"Function Name: {function_name}")
        print(f"Arguments: {arguments}")
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Function Name: cal_min_ssc
Arguments: ['min_wage', 'tax_rate', 'min_profit']
```

Comment: I am trying to read file from the hard drive, and I received this error :
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: You probably need to iterate through the list as in `for line in lines:` , and then split the line (which hopefully is a string).  @silent_hunter